# How to transform one vector drawing in node pdfkit

Tags: node-pdfkit

I don't know how to draw two independent vector graphics and apply tranformation on one of them.

My code:

```
doc.moveTo(0, 20)
    .lineTo(200, 20)
    .rotate(45)
    .stroke();

doc.moveTo(0, 40)
    .lineTo(200, 40)
    .stroke();
```

All I want is, to have first drawing rotated and the second not. But both are rotated and I cannot find how to transform (rotate, scale) only one of them. Can anybody help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the graphics stack `save()` and `restore()` methods:

```
doc.save()
doc.moveTo(0, 20).lineTo(200, 20).rotate(45).stroke()
doc.restore()
doc.moveTo(0, 40).lineTo(200, 40).stroke()
```

I think methods like `rotate()` apply to the document, not just the line (this this case), so you can save the graphics stack, make changes, then restore the graphics stack to what it was before.

From : [PDFKit - Transformations](http://pdfkit.org/docs/vector.html#transformations)

> The rotate transformation takes an angle and optionally, an object with an origin property. **It rotates the document** angle degrees around the passed origin or by default, the center of the page.

See: [PDFKit - Saving and restoring the graphics stack](http://pdfkit.org/docs/vector.html#saving_and_restoring_the_graphics_stack)